# Symfony data transformer after $form->isValid()

Tags: php, forms, symfony, data-transfer-objects

I ran into a trouble of understanding how exactly data is processed in [DataTransformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) of **Symfony**.

I have a just a password form. Just one field. This field belongs to the User entity which has to constraints defined in `.yml` file.

```
Software\Bundle\Entity\User:
    password:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 6
            max: 155
```

The validation works fine, as supposed to. The problem arise when password must be encoded automatically from the field. So,

```
    $builder->add('password', 'password', [
        'label' => 'word.password'
    ]);

    $builder->get('password')
        ->addModelTransformer(new EncodePasswordTransformer());
```

And the transformer itself:

```
class EncodePasswordTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        // encode password
        return PasswordHash::createHash($value);
    }
}
```

So here's what's happening:

The form should contain 6 to 155 characters but `$form->isValid()` is always true, because the `PasswordHash::createHash($value)` encodes the password to 32 characters. What I was expecting is:

Form validates raw password, if more than 6 chars then go to `$form->isValid()` true and then encode the password after it's validated.

I know I can just encode the password manually while the form is valid without using `DataTransformer` but I was hoping for a bit more elegant way.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, according to the [documents](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-and-forms).

> Symfony's form library uses the validator service internally to validate the underlying object after values have been submitted.

So you're not actually validating form, but the object underneath which has no "notion" of the plain password.
A not so elegant solution would be to include a plain password field on your user and **not persist** it. However you probably won't be able to validate your existing user objects (e.g: in an update form), since their plain password fields will be `null`. To get around that you could create a custom validator that checks the validity of the `$plainPassword` field only if the user is not **new**. You could check that by using doctrine's `UnitOfWork` or by checking if the `id` of the user is `null`.
I suggest you also take a look at `FOSUserBundle` it has (or had) a similar approach to the plain password field and **might** have what you're looking for.