# Alternative to $form->isValid() for use in a Symfony DataMapper?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, datamapper

I am building a Symfony data transformer class called `EventDataMapper`. It handles two fields: A TextType field called  My `mapDataToForms()` definition looks like this:

```
public function mapDataToForms($data, $forms)
{
    $existingTitle = $data->getTitle();
    $existingAttendees = $data->getAttendees();
    $this->propertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms($data, $forms);
    foreach ($forms as $index => $form) {
        if ($form->getName() === 'title' && !is_null($existingTitle)) {
            $form->setData($existingTitle);
        }
        if ($form->getName() === 'attendees' && !is_null($existingAttendees)) {
            $form->setData($existingAttendees);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm setting data before validation runs, so if I submit a form with a non-numeric string in the "attendees" field, I get an ugly TransformationFailedException ('Unable to transform value for property path "attendees": Expected a numeric'). And if I try to do a check for whether my field is valid by adding a call to `$form->isValid()` in the line before I call `$form->setData()`, I get a LogicException. ('Cannot check if an unsubmitted form is valid. Call Form::isSubmitted() before Form::isValid().')

**Is there any way for my to preemptively call a validator on this specific field from within my DataMapper?**

(Yes, this can be somewhat prevented with frontend logic. But I don't want to rely too much on that.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony data transformer after $form->isValid()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665297/symfony-data-transformer-after-form-isvalid)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Apologies -- I accidentally wrote DataTransformer in the title. This question relates to a DataMapper, not a transformer.

Comment: Did you do this and any other part of this if you did?https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html#using-the-mapper

Comment: I haven't tried using callbacks. I can give that a whack.

Comment: As you wish, but personally I don't have any other solutions to propose. If you prefer, you can wait for other solutions before starting. Keep courage and good dev!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Based on your example I have the assumption that you have an input field. And when it's empty, the original data is not altered. 

Are you using Data Mappers correctly? It's to map data from parent forms (FormTypes) to child forms (FormTypes).  That's way before doing any validation, because validation can only be done after all the data is in the right place. 

And second, if your input field is empty, it's never`null`, it's `empty()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Leroy. I've switched it to use `empty()`. Here are the gory details of my plight, which I left out of the original post for simplicity: I'm combining two existing, very similar controllers (with accompanying form types) into one controller. In order to do that, I need to translate the names of some fields while breaking up some specialized child form types into their constituent fields, and I'm using a DataMapper as part of that process. I hope that helps explain why I'm presenting this somewhat wacky scenario. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Instead of magically mapping data (which could be a risk btw, you should never trust the user), you can also use a factory method for it. And pass in the desired Changes, like a conditional different FormType.

Comment: Thanks -- sounds like a solid idea, though I'm not quite sure how I would implement it off the top of my head. If you put a few more details into an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the loop on this. Here's what we did.

A colleague made a new form type corresponding to a new adapter class that wraps our two previous classes, providing a uniform set of wrapper methods for interacting with them.

We passed Symfony's validator service into our new form type using the constructor.

In that form type, we're using `$builder->addEventListener()` to add a callback/listener on the `POST_SUBMIT` event. Here's the callback:

```
        function(FormEvent $event): void {
            $adapter = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $errors = $adapter->propagate($this->validator);

            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $formError = new FormError($error->getMessage());
                $targetPath = self::mapPropertyPath($error->getPropertyPath());
                $target = $targetPath !== null ? $form->get($targetPath) : $form;
                $target->addError($formError);
            }
        }
```

The adapter, in turn, has some logic that does various translations of data into a form that can be used in our legacy classes, followed by this:

```
return $validator->validate($this->legacyObject);
```

This works well for us. I hope it helps somebody else out too.